# How to check if a compnent is re-rendered or not in React?

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I've been working with React for nearly 3 years, but sometimes run into difficulties in "Rendering" meaning.

Practically, to check "Rendering" I just put

```js
console.log('render')
```

In a component right before

```js
return <>...</>
```

Is this correct check? Or Can't I know whether it's re-rendered or not?

Comment: Well yes, or just visually see if the expected elements are displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare a variable outside of the component and and initialize it to `0` and then increment it from inside the component:

```
let count = 0;
const Component = () => {
count++;
console.log("component render number: ", count);
//...
}
```

this trick will let you see the logs

```
component render number: n
```

each time the function is invoked, because the component is a function after all, but the component might be only invoked without rerendering, therefore what you are doing is not the correct way to check.

---

To understand that we can try this simple code without strict mode:

```js
let count = 0;
const Component = () => {

count ++;
console.log("component render number: ", count);

const [test, setTest] = useState(0);

return (
  <>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setTest(1);
      }}
    >
      click me
    </button>
  </>
);
```

here we will see first

```
component render number: 1
```

we also know that the component rerenders only when the state takes a **different value** so when we click the button the first time we expect to see

```
component render number: 2
```

because the state value passes from `0` to `1`, and this happens.

Now when we click the button again, we don't expect to see

```
component render number: 3
```

because the state takes the same exact value so the component does not have to rerender, however we see the logs anyway.

### why this is happening?

In fact in this case the component didn't rerendered, but only invoked

> If you return the same value from a Reducer Hook as the current state, React will **bail out without rendering the children or firing effects**. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)

### short answer

If you want to see logs only when the component rerenders, the simplest way is to make a `useEffect` hook **without a dependency array**, this will make it run after each component render:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("component rerendered");
});
```

Now when we click the button the second time we see only

```
component render number: 3
```

and no

```
component rerendered
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not able to comment yet, but to build on what the answer about the react developer tools:

- Open the "Profiler"
- Click the settings icon (top right - "view settings")
- In the "General" tab, check "Highlight updates when components render."

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Better to use hook `useEffect` and check it inside

Answer (score 0):

Check React Developer Tools and profiler. When turned on, the re rendered components will flash on your screen.

Comment: Could you descrive the detail operation of it? I got used to using it, but never seen if the component are re-rendered.

Comment: Get react dev tools in chrome, open you page, open chrome dev tools and you should see components and profiler added to your tabs. Under components -> general there is an option called "Highlight updates when components render." All components that are re-rendered should flash. Quite a few other options there, but this one can be quite useful to see re renders on a glance.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt use this so far.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).